# How to modify a TFS item by using Powershell

Tags: powershell, team-foundation-server

I connected to VSTS Server by using:

```
$teamProjectCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection("http://wonderful01:8080")

$ws = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([type]"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore")

$closebug=$ws.getworkitem(801089)
```

After that I ran `$closebug`, and got one of the items I need to modify:

```
Value                    : Fixed
OriginalValue            : Fixed
FieldDefinition          : Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.FieldDefinition
Id                       : 10001
Name                     : Substatus
ReferenceName            : Microsoft.SQL.Substatus
IsDirty                  : False
IsEditable               : True
IsComputed               : False
IsRequired               : True
AllowedValues            : {Verification Not Needed, Verified}
HasAllowedValuesList     : True
IsLimitedToAllowedValues : True
ProhibitedValues         : {}
HasPatternMatch          : False
Status                   : InvalidListValue
IsValid                  : False
WorkItem                 : Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem
```

So how can I change the vaule from "fixed" to "verified"?

Comment: Anybody know something about this?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am coming to answer my question. After a long time investigation I found that substatus could be invoked by:

```
$closebug.fields[54]
```

To change value from "fixed" to "resolved", use:

```
$closebug.fields[54].value="resolved"
```

Then update the change:

```
$closebug.save()
```

I am not quite understanding why it works, and I think there should be a better way to do it. Welcome comments.